# Как сделать доступными устанавливаемые приложения в хроме (Chrome Installable apps)?

Tags: google-chrome, web-apps, chrome-extension

Как сделать доступными устанавливаемые приложения в хроме (Chrome Installable apps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого необходимо запускать браузер с флагом

```
  --enable-apps --apps-panel
```

Я изменяю параметры запуска у ярлыка браузера. Выберем ярлык хрома, нажимаем правую клавишу мыши и выберем пункт "свойства". Добавляем флаг после имени.